# Existence of a transitive smooth G-action of $G\times G$

Tags: lie-groups, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, group-actions, equivariant-maps

This question arose from an attempt of using the Equivariant Rank Theorem to prove question 7.1 of Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds.

The Equivariant Rank Theorem is stated:

> Let M and N be smooth manifolds
> and let G be a Lie group. Suppose $F:M\rightarrow N$ is a smooth map that is equivariant
> with respect to a transitive smooth G-action on M and any smooth G-action on N.
> Then F has constant rank. Thus, if F is surjective, it is a smooth submersion; if it is
> injective, it is a smooth immersion; and if it is bijective, it is a diffeomorphism.

Question 7.1 is stated:

> Show that for any Lie group G, the multiplication map $m: G\times G \rightarrow G$ is a
> smooth submersion. [Hint: use local sections.]

I was thus attempting to prove 7.1 through use of the equivariant rank theorem. I will outline my progress; however, the question of this post can be viewed disjoint from the context of this problem.

My attempt:

> We know that m is surjective, as for any h in G, consider $(e,h)  \in G\times G$. Then $m(e,h)=e*h=h$. So, if we can show the preliminary conditions in the theorem, we are done, as surjectivity implies smooth submersion.

> Given that G is a Lie group, it is of course a smooth manifold by definition. Therefore $G\times G$ is as well, so m is a map between smooth manifolds. Since G is a Lie group, we also know that m is a smooth map.

The equivariant part is where my question emerges:

> We need a transitive smooth G-action on $G\times G$, and any smooth action on G, where m is equivariant. For the smooth action on G, I was considering the trivial action, say $\theta$, which is smooth. However, m just multiplies the two coordinates of $G\times G$, so if we were to find a transitive smooth G-action from $G\times G$ to $G\times G$, say $\phi$, it would necessarily need to be trivial in order to commute with $m \circ \theta$ (as $m\circ\theta(p_1,p_2)=m(p_1,p_2)=(p_1p_2$). But the trivial action is not transitive, so we need another path.

My issue is that no matter which smooth G-action from G to G I pick, it seems that the overarching issue is finding a transitive smooth G-action from $G\times G$ to $G\times G$ at all. Thus, my gut is saying there does not exist one, but how can I be sure?

Comment: You should be using the transitive action of $G^2$ instead.

Comment: @MoisheKohan hmm. Do you mean instead of G-actions, in the context of the statement of the equivariant rank theorem, I should consider $G\times G$-actions, and then maybe I can find ones satisfying the conditions?

Comment: That's right...

Comment: Ah, so then for a transitive smooth $G^2$-action from $G^2$ to $G^2$, say for $(p_1,p_2)$ to $(h_1,h_2)$, we can take $\theta_{h_1{p_1}^-1} \times \theta_{h_2{p_2}^-1}$. And for any smooth $G^2$-action from G to G, we can just take $\phi_{h_1h_2{p_2}^{-1}{p_1}^{-1}} \times e$. Since all the maps involved are left translations and trivial actions, we have smoothness, and specifically the left translations are transitive.

Comment: I see would mix left and right translations to ensure equivariance of the product map. $(g,h)*(x,y)=(gx,yh^{-1})$ defines an action of $(g,h)$ on $(x,y)$. Similarly, the action of $(g,h)$ on $z\in G$ is given by $gzh^{-1}$

Comment: So your first construction is transitive since if we want to go from $(p_1,p_2)$ to $(h_1,h_2)$, we can look at left action by $(h_1{p_1}^{-1}, {h_2}^{-1}p_2)$. And clearly the second construction is smooth. And they commute, so we satisfy the conditions for the theorem!

Comment: I’m confused why you want to use the equivariant rank theorem here. Can’t you prove this directly using the fact the differential at each point is the sun of two linear isomorphisms?

Comment: There are definitely other and probably more instructional ways, but I was just curious about this path!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your gut feeling is correct. Assume there is a smooth, transitive action $\theta\colon G \times G^2 \to G^2$. Pick some $p \in G^2$. As $\theta$ is transitive, the orbit map $\theta^{(p)}\colon G \to G^2$, $g \mapsto g . p$ is surjective, and since it is equivariant with regards to the left-multiplication action of $G$ on itself and $\theta$ on the codomain (!), the equivariant rank theorem tells you it is a smooth submersion. But unless $G$ is discrete this is absurd, seeing as $\dim G^2 = 2 \dim G$.

Comment: Ah, of course -- The dimensions helped me see this. Thanks!